# req.file is undefined when uploading an image through Postman

Tags: node.js, postman

I am trying to write a code that is uploading an image (jpg / png), and the req.file in the code is undefined. I have tried to change it to req.files, and same thing.

```js
 const express=require('express');
 const mongoose= require('mongoose');
const bodyparser=require('body-parser');
const cookieParser=require('cookie-parser');
 const multer = require("multer");
 
 var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, './public/uploads')
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, file.originalname)
    }
})

const fileFilter = (req, file, cb)=>{
    if(file.mimetype === 'image/jpg' ||  file.mimetype === 'image/png'){
        cb(null,true);
    }else{
        cb(null,false);
    }
}

const upload = multer({
    storage:storage,
    fileFilter:fileFilter
});


app.post('/api/uploadPicture', upload.single('picture'), (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.files);
    if(req.file) {
        const pathName = req.file.path;
        res.send(req.file,pathName);
    }
    else throw 'error';
});
```

[image]

Any ideas? Why is that happening ?

Comment: Please append your console logs, too.

Comment: try to remove fileFilter once and check if it works or not.. share the results then lets debug after that